# How can i filter date in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i use this code - live example:

http://live.datatables.net/zuzimeq/1/edit

But i can only enter a number without a '/' or '.' or something like that.
So how can i filter the date column?

Thanks for helping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current function is parsing your entry and look for age field. It needs to be

```
var min = $('#min').val();
var max = $('#max').val();
var date =  data[4]; // use data for the age column

if ( ( min == '' && max == '' ) ||
     ( min == '' && date <= max ) ||
     ( min <= date && '' == max ) ||
     ( min <= date && date <= max ) )
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

http://live.datatables.net/benixip/3/edit